# Which is the maximum number of keys in authorized_keys file?

Tags: ssh-keys

I'm developing a solution which inserts a big number of SSH-keys into the authorized keys files of my SSH-server. Does anyone know the limit of keys that you can insert into that file? Are we talking about a hundred, thousand or tens of thousands? Any idea? And how is the performance affected when you have a large number of keys?

I suppose it is preferable to divide keys between various users, but I would like to know the limits of one user.

Comment: This is a good question for testing. From the fact that the file is plain text we can assume that there is no indexing, and the complexity to find a certain key should be at least linear - O(n).

Comment: It's what I thought, but I'm asking because if someone has experience in that case it will be useful. I will update this post with my testing. Thank's!

Comment: If you are really looking at thousands you might want to look at the newish CA support.  You might be able to just add the CA key.

Comment: In OpenSSH 6.2 there is a feature that may be of help to you: http://article.gmane.org/gmane.os.openbsd.announce/171 - "sshd(8): Added a sshd_config(5) option AuthorizedKeysCommand to support fetching authorized_keys from a command in addition to (or instead of) from the filesystem. The command is run under an account specified by an AuthorizedKeysCommandUser sshd_config(5) option."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no limit to the number of entries in the file. From the source code

```
auth2-pubkey.c 
/* return 1 if user allows given key */
static int
user_key_allowed2(struct passwd *pw, Key *key, char *file)
{ ...

while (read_keyfile_line(f, file, line, sizeof(line), &linenum) != -1) {
    char *cp, *key_options = NULL;
```

As you can see this simply loops over the file until read_keyfile_line returns -1.

Answer (score 2):

There is no limit, but finding the correct key will be slow, like GREPing a large text file.

Comment: What is the alternative?